# root@localhost permission denied ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, localhost, root

I installed ssh in my Ubuntu 14.04. I followed a tutorial for generating ssh keys. I used following commands to set the keys.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

when I type ssh localhost as a normal user it will not ask for any passwords and it works fine but when do it as a root it is asking for root@localhost password and my root password is not working.

Here is what I have tried so far by visiting some stackoverflow.com questions regarding this error.

1. Everyone suggested to create a password by "sudo su" then "passwd". I tried it. I created a password and it's not working. I tried it several times.
2. I tried "ssh-add" as root but it says `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent`
3. I  tried generating the keys as root by doing `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""` then `cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`. After doing this when I start `ssh localhost` it is asking for root@localhost password and it is not accepting my root password.
4. I tried changing PermitRootLogin to yes and withoutpassword. both did not work.
5. I added a new property to the sshd_config saying `AllowUsers root`. It also did not work.

Thanks in advance. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you manage to find solution?

Answer (score 2):

If u have not given password for root and you are trying to fire command on spark or haddop like `./sbin/stop-all.sh` or `./sbin/start-all.sh` . If you don't have a root password, you can setup one using

```
sudo passwd
```

and fire commands.